# Insert difficulties with SQLite database (for android)

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I've some problems with my code. I need to develop an app with some info about shops. It's a one table database. Here are my 4 java files.

```
`package com.example.rpata.roxyapp;

public class TableBoutique {
private int BTQ_KEY ;
private String BTQ_NAME ;
private String BTQ_TYPE ;
private String BTQ_SITE ;
private String BTQ_CLKAM1 ;
private String BTQ_CLKAM2 ;
private String BTQ_CLKPM1 ;
private String BTQ_CLKPM2 ;
private String BTQ_PHONE ;
private String BTQ_LOGO ;

public TableBoutique() {}

public TableBoutique(String BTQ_NAME, String BTQ_TYPE, String BTQ_SITE, String BTQ_CLKAM1, String BTQ_CLKAM2, String BTQ_CLKPM1, String BTQ_CLKPM2, String BTQ_PHONE, String BTQ_LOGO) {
    this.BTQ_NAME = BTQ_NAME;
    this.BTQ_TYPE = BTQ_TYPE;
    this.BTQ_SITE = BTQ_SITE;
    this.BTQ_CLKAM1 = BTQ_CLKAM1;
    this.BTQ_CLKAM2 = BTQ_CLKAM2;
    this.BTQ_CLKPM1 = BTQ_CLKPM1;
    this.BTQ_CLKPM2 = BTQ_CLKPM2;
    this.BTQ_PHONE = BTQ_PHONE;
    this.BTQ_LOGO = BTQ_LOGO;
}

//methodes pour la cle
public int getBTQKey() {
    return BTQ_KEY;
}
public void setBTQKey(int BTQ_KEY) {
    this.BTQ_KEY = BTQ_KEY;
}


//methodes pour le nom
public String getBTQName() {
    return BTQ_NAME;
}
public void setBTQName(String BTQ_NAME) {
    this.BTQ_NAME = BTQ_NAME;
}


//methodes pour le type de boutique
public String getBTQType() {
    return BTQ_TYPE;
}
public void setBTQType(String BTQ_TYPE) {
    this.BTQ_TYPE = BTQ_TYPE;
}


//methodes pour le site
public String getBTQSite() {
    return BTQ_SITE;
}
public void setBTQSite(String BTQ_SITE) {
    this.BTQ_SITE = BTQ_SITE;
}


//methodes pour la premiere heure du matin
public String getBTQClkam1() {
    return BTQ_CLKAM1;
}
public void setBTQClkam1(String BTQ_CLKAM1) {
    this.BTQ_CLKAM1 = BTQ_CLKAM1;
}


//methodes pour la deuxieme heure du matin
public String getBTQClkam2() {
    return BTQ_CLKAM2;
}
public void setBTQClkam2(String BTQ_CLKAM2) {
    this.BTQ_CLKAM2 = BTQ_CLKAM2;
}


//methodes pour la premiere heure de l apres-midi
public String getBTQClkpm1() {
    return BTQ_CLKPM1;
}
public void setBTQClkpm1(String BTQ_CLKPM1) {
    this.BTQ_CLKPM1 = BTQ_CLKPM1;
}


//methodes pour la deuxieme heure de l apres-midi
public String getBTQClkpm2() {
    return BTQ_CLKAM2;
}
public void setBTQClkpm2(String BTQ_CLKPM2) {
    this.BTQ_CLKPM2 = BTQ_CLKPM2;
}


//methodes pour le numero de telephone du service client de la boutique
public String getBTQPhone() {
    return BTQ_PHONE;
}
public void setBTQPhone(String BTQ_PHONE) {
    this.BTQ_PHONE = BTQ_PHONE;
}

//methodes pour le chemin d acces au fichier du logo
public String getBTQLogo() {
    return BTQ_LOGO;
}
public void setBTQLogo(String BTQ_LOGO) {
    this.BTQ_LOGO = BTQ_LOGO;
}


public String toString(){
    return "Id of the store: "+BTQ_KEY+"\n name of the store: "+BTQ_NAME+
            "\n type of store :"+BTQ_TYPE+"\n website of the store: "+BTQ_SITE+
            "\n open morning at :"+BTQ_CLKAM1+"\n close morning at :"+BTQ_CLKAM2+
            "\n open afternoon at :"+BTQ_CLKPM1+"\n close afternoon at :"+BTQ_CLKPM2;
}
```

}`

```
`package com.example.rpata.roxyapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

/* Ce fichier s'occupe de la création de la base de données , des mises a jours globales*/

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

// on enregistre les attributs, tables et requetes dans des constantes
//de facon a les retrouver et les modifier plus facilement
//c est public
//parce qu on manipule la base en dehors de cette classe

//version de la base de donnees
private static final int db_version = 2;


//nom de la base de donness
private static final String database_name = "BDDdelappli";

//nom des tables

private static final String BOUTIQUE_TABLE = "tableBoutique";

private static final String BTK_KEY = "boutiqueId";//----------------col 0
private static final String BTK_NAME = "boutiqueNom";//--------------col 1
private static final String BTK_TYPE = "boutiqueType";//-------------col 2
private static final String BTK_SITE = "boutiqueSite";//-------------col 3
private static final String BTK_CLKAM1 = "boutiqueClockAm1";//-------col 4
private static final String BTK_CLKAM2 = "boutiqueClockAm2";//-------col 5
private static final String BTK_CLKPM1 = "boutiqueClockPm1";//-------col 6
private static final String BTK_CLKPM2 = "boutiqueClockPm2";//-------col 7
private static final String BTK_PHONE = "boutiqueTelephone";//-------col 8
private static final String BTK_LOGO = "boutiqueLogo";//-------------col 9




//table boutique
public static final String CREATE_BDD_BOUTIQUE =
        "CREATE TABLE " + BOUTIQUE_TABLE + " ( " +
                BTK_KEY + "  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT , " +
                BTK_NAME + " TEXT, " + BTK_TYPE + " TEXT, " + BTK_SITE + " TEXT, " +
                BTK_CLKAM1 + " REAL, " + BTK_CLKAM2 + " REAL, " +
                BTK_CLKPM1 + " REAL, " + BTK_CLKPM2 + " REAL, " +
                BTK_PHONE + " TEXT, " + BTK_LOGO + " TEXT) ; ";



public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, database_name
            , null, db_version);
    Log.d("DataBaseHelper", "DB created");

}


@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase bdd) {
    Log.d("DatabaseHelper", "je vais tenter de faire le onCreate");
    // on execute une requete SQL pour laquelle on ne veut pas de reponse
    // on utilise execSQL quand on veut faire un SELECT , UPDATE , INSERT ou DELETE
    // on cree les tables

    bdd.execSQL(CREATE_BDD_BOUTIQUE);
    Log.d("DataBaseHelper", "table_boutique created");

}

  @Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase bdd, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
      Log.d("DatabaseHelper", "je vais tenter de mettre a jour ma bdd");
    // on supprime les tables qui existent
    //bdd.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + LIEUX_TABLE + ";");
    bdd.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + BOUTIQUE_TABLE + ";");
    // on cree les nouvelles
    onCreate(bdd);
}

@Override
public void onOpen(SQLiteDatabase bdd){
    super.onOpen(bdd);
    if(!bdd.isReadOnly()){
        bdd.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys= ON ");
    }
}
```

}
`

```
`package com.example.rpata.roxyapp;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.util.Log;

public class BDD_Operation {


private static final String BTK_KEY = "boutiqueId";
private static final int NUM_BTK_KEY = 0;
private static final String BTK_NAME = "boutiqueNom";
private static final int NUM_BTK_NAME = 1;
private static final String BTK_TYPE = "boutiqueType";
private static final int NUM_BTK_TYPE = 2;
private static final String BTK_SITE = "boutiqueSite";
private static final int NUM_BTK_SITE = 3;
private static final String BTK_CLKAM1 = "boutiqueClockAm1";
private static final int NUM_BTK_CLKAM1 = 4;
private static final String BTK_CLKAM2 = "boutiqueClockAm2";
private static final int NUM_BTK_CLKAM2 = 5;
private static final String BTK_CLKPM1 = "boutiqueClockPm1";
private static final int NUM_BTK_CLKPM1 = 6;
private static final String BTK_CLKPM2 = "boutiqueClockPm2";
private static final int NUM_BTK_CLKPM2 = 7;
private static final String BTK_PHONE = "boutiqueTelephone";
private static final int NUM_BTK_PHONE = 8;
private static final String BTK_LOGO = "boutiqueLogo";
private static final int NUM_BTK_LOGO = 9;



private String BOUTIQUE_TABLE = "tableBoutique";

private DatabaseHelper dbh;
private SQLiteDatabase bdd;

public BDD_Operation(Context context){
    //On crée la BDD
    dbh = new DatabaseHelper(context);
}

public void open(){
    //on ouvre la BDD en écriture
    bdd = dbh.getWritableDatabase();
}

public void close(){
    //on ferme l'accès à la BDD
    bdd.close();
}

public SQLiteDatabase getBDD(){
    return bdd;
}


/***********************************************INSERT**************************************/


public long insertBoutique(TableBoutique boutiq) {
    Log.d("BDD_Operation", "on essaye d inserer une boutique");
    //Création d un ContentValues (fonctionne comme une HashMap)
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    //on lui ajoute une valeur associé à une clé (qui est le nom de la colonne dans laquelle on veut mettre la valeur)
    values.put(BTK_KEY, boutiq.getBTQKey());
    Log.d("BDD_Operation", "j ai la cle");
    values.put(BTK_NAME, boutiq.getBTQName());
    Log.d("BDD_Operation", "j ai le nom de la boutique");
    values.put(BTK_TYPE, boutiq.getBTQType());
    Log.d("BDD_Operation", "j ai le type");
    values.put(BTK_SITE, boutiq.getBTQSite());
    Log.d("BDD_Operation", "j ai le site");
    values.put(BTK_CLKAM1, boutiq.getBTQClkam1());
    Log.d("BDD_Operation", "j ai l heure du matin");
    values.put(BTK_CLKAM2, boutiq.getBTQClkam2());
    Log.d("BDD_Operation", "j ai l heure du matin");
    values.put(BTK_CLKPM1, boutiq.getBTQClkpm1());
    Log.d("BDD_Operation", "j ai l heure de laprem");
    values.put(BTK_CLKPM2, boutiq.getBTQClkpm2());
    Log.d("BDD_Operation", "j ai l heure de laprem");
    values.put(BTK_PHONE, boutiq.getBTQPhone());
    Log.d("BDD_Operation", "j ai le num de tel");
    values.put(BTK_LOGO, boutiq.getBTQLogo());
    Log.d("BDD_Operation", "j ai le logo");

    //on insère l'objet dans la BDD via le ContentValues
    return bdd.insert(BOUTIQUE_TABLE, null, values);
    //Log.d("BDD_Operation"," boutiq inserted");
}


/**************************************RECHERCHE***********************************/

//rechercher une boutique par son nom
public TableBoutique getBoutiqueWithItsName(String name_of_shop) {
    Cursor b2 = bdd.query(BOUTIQUE_TABLE, new String[]{BTK_KEY, BTK_NAME, BTK_TYPE, BTK_SITE, BTK_CLKAM1, BTK_CLKAM2, BTK_CLKPM1, BTK_CLKPM2, BTK_PHONE, BTK_LOGO}
            , BTK_NAME + " LIKE \"" + name_of_shop +"\"", null, null, null, null);
    return cursor2ToBoutique(b2);
}

private TableBoutique cursor2ToBoutique (Cursor b2) {

    if (b2.getCount() == 0)
        return null;

    b2.moveToFirst();

    TableBoutique boutique = new TableBoutique();

    //Log.d("BDD_Operation", "je rentre dans le while pour recuperer les donnees");
    boutique.setBTQKey(b2.getInt(NUM_BTK_KEY));
   // Log.d("BDD_Operation", "j ai fait ca ou pas ?");
    boutique.setBTQName(b2.getString(NUM_BTK_NAME));
    boutique.setBTQType(b2.getString(NUM_BTK_TYPE));
    boutique.setBTQSite(b2.getString(NUM_BTK_SITE));
    boutique.setBTQClkam1(b2.getString(NUM_BTK_CLKAM1));
    boutique.setBTQClkam2(b2.getString(NUM_BTK_CLKAM2));
    boutique.setBTQClkpm1(b2.getString(NUM_BTK_CLKPM1));
    boutique.setBTQClkpm2(b2.getString(NUM_BTK_CLKPM2));
    boutique.setBTQPhone(b2.getString(NUM_BTK_PHONE));
    boutique.setBTQLogo(b2.getString(NUM_BTK_LOGO));
   // Log.d("BDD_Operation", "je vais sortir du while et on va fermer le cursor");
    //b2.moveToNext();

    b2.close();
    Log.d("BDD_Operation", "j ai ferme le cursor");

    return boutique;
}


//rechercher une boutique par son identifiant
public TableBoutique getBoutiqueWithItsKey(String key) {
    Log.d("BDD_Operation", "demande de recherche d'une boutique par son identifiant");
    Cursor b = bdd.query(BOUTIQUE_TABLE, new String[]{BTK_KEY, BTK_NAME, BTK_TYPE, BTK_SITE, BTK_CLKAM1, BTK_CLKAM2, BTK_CLKPM1, BTK_CLKPM2, BTK_PHONE, BTK_LOGO}
            , BTK_KEY + " LIKE \"" + key +"\"", null, null, null, null);
    return cursorToBoutique(b);
}

private TableBoutique cursorToBoutique (Cursor b) {

    if (b.getCount() == 0)
        return null;

    b.moveToFirst();

    TableBoutique boutique = new TableBoutique();

    Log.d("BDD_Operation", "je vais recuperer les donnees");
    boutique.setBTQKey(b.getInt(NUM_BTK_KEY));
    Log.d("BDD_Operation", "j ai commence la recuperation de donnees");
    boutique.setBTQName(b.getString(NUM_BTK_NAME));
    boutique.setBTQType(b.getString(NUM_BTK_TYPE));
    boutique.setBTQSite(b.getString(NUM_BTK_SITE));
    boutique.setBTQClkam1(b.getString(NUM_BTK_CLKAM1));
    boutique.setBTQClkam2(b.getString(NUM_BTK_CLKAM2));
    boutique.setBTQClkpm1(b.getString(NUM_BTK_CLKPM1));
    boutique.setBTQClkpm2(b.getString(NUM_BTK_CLKPM2));
    boutique.setBTQPhone(b.getString(NUM_BTK_PHONE));
    boutique.setBTQLogo(b.getString(NUM_BTK_LOGO));
     Log.d("BDD_Operation", "j ai recupere les donnees et on va fermer le cursor");


    b.close();
    Log.d("BDD_Operation", "j ai ferme le cursor");

    return boutique;
}

    /********************UPDATE********************************/



public int updateBoutiqueByKey(int BOUTIQUE_KEY, TableBoutique boutique){
    //La mise à jour d'une Boutique dans la BDD fonctionne plus ou moins comme une insertion
    //il faut simple préciser quelle boutique on doit mettre à jour grâce à sa cle primaire
    Log.d("BDD_Operation", "test mise a jour");
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(BTK_NAME, boutique.getBTQName());
    values.put(BTK_TYPE, boutique.getBTQType());
    values.put(BTK_SITE, boutique.getBTQSite());
    values.put(BTK_CLKAM1, boutique.getBTQClkam1());
    values.put(BTK_CLKAM2, boutique.getBTQClkam2());
    values.put(BTK_CLKPM1, boutique.getBTQClkpm1());
    values.put(BTK_CLKPM2, boutique.getBTQClkpm2());
    values.put(BTK_PHONE, boutique.getBTQPhone());
    values.put(BTK_LOGO, boutique.getBTQLogo());
    Log.d("BDD_Operation", "mise a jour quasi terminée");
    return bdd.update(BOUTIQUE_TABLE, values, BTK_KEY + " = " +BOUTIQUE_KEY, null);
}


public int updateBoutiqueByName(String name, TableBoutique boutique){
    //La mise à jour d'une Boutique dans la BDD fonctionne plus ou moins comme une insertion
    //il faut simple préciser quelle boutique on doit mettre à jour grâce à sa cle primaire
    Log.d("BDD_Operation", "test mise a jour par le nom");
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(BTK_NAME, boutique.getBTQName());
    values.put(BTK_TYPE, boutique.getBTQType());
    values.put(BTK_SITE, boutique.getBTQSite());
    values.put(BTK_CLKAM1, boutique.getBTQClkam1());
    values.put(BTK_CLKAM2, boutique.getBTQClkam2());
    values.put(BTK_CLKPM1, boutique.getBTQClkpm1());
    values.put(BTK_CLKPM2, boutique.getBTQClkpm2());
    values.put(BTK_PHONE, boutique.getBTQPhone());
    values.put(BTK_LOGO, boutique.getBTQLogo());
    Log.d("BDD_Operation", "mise a jour quasi terminée");
    return bdd.update(BOUTIQUE_TABLE, values, BTK_NAME + " = " +name, null);
}




/****************************************DELETE******************************************/


public int removeBoutiqueByKey(int id){
//Suppression d'une boutique de la BDD grâce à l'ID
 return bdd.delete(BOUTIQUE_TABLE, BTK_KEY + " = " +id, null);
}
```

}
`

```
`package com.example.rpata.roxyapp;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Création d'une instance de ma classe BDD_Operation
    BDD_Operation bdd = new BDD_Operation(this);
    //Log.d("MainActivity", "La base de donnees est instanciee");
    // ok ca le fait

    //Création des boutique
    TableBoutique zara = new TableBoutique("Zara", "mode homme femme enfant", "www.zara.com", "9.3f", "12", "14"," 19.3f","0000000000", "logozara.jpg");

    //On ouvre la base de données pour écrire dedans
    bdd.open();
    //Log.d("MainActivity", "ouverture de la base de données");
    // ok ca le fait

    //On insère la boutique que l'on vient de créer
   // Log.d("MainActivity", "blabla");
    bdd.insertBoutique(zara);
    //Log.d("MainActivity", "bliblibli");




   // Pour vérifier que l'on a bien créé nos entités dans la BDD on les extrait de la BDD grâce au nom
    TableBoutique test = bdd.getBoutiqueWithItsName(zara.getBTQName());

    //Si une boutique est retournée
    if (test != null) {
        String TAG1 = "INSERTION";
        Log.d(TAG1, "boutique ajoutée");
        //On affiche les infos du lieux dans un Toast
        Toast.makeText(this, test.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //On modifie la ville du lieux
        test.setBTQName("J'ai modifié le nom de la boutique");
        Log.d("MainActivity", "modification du nom de la boutique");
        //Puis on met à jour la BDD
        bdd.updateBoutiqueByKey(test.getBTQKey(), test);
        }



    bdd.close();

}
```

}
`
The first time I run my app, the insertion works, BUT, if I run a second time my app, the insertion failed (I got a message telling that my column boutiqueId -which is my first column- doesn't exist in my table)
I am using Android Studio. I don't know what do to now. Could someone help me please? 
By the way, I'm a member of a group, your help would help 5 students.

I've change the line in my insert function 
`values.put(BTK_KEY, boutiq.getBTQKey());
    Log.d("BDD_Operation", "j ai la cle");`
I've remove the - ' - of my task in the Main: 
`test.setBTQName("J'ai modifié le nom de la boutique");`
 And now I've got this message in my logcat:
    `D/BDD_Operation: mise a jour quasi terminée 
    E/SQLiteLog: (1) near "ai": syntax error 
    D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM – Rxn Olcylk 1 hour ago

```
beginning of crash E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: PID: 2486         ComponentInfo{.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "ai":         syntax error (code 1):
```

, while compiling: UPDATE tableBoutique SET boutiqueClockPm2=?,boutiqueClockPm1=?,boutiqueClockAm2=?,
boutiqueTelephone=?,bou‌tiqueClockAm1=?,boutiqueNom=?,
boutiqueLogo=?,boutiqueType=?,boutiqueSite=? WHERE 
boutiqueNom = J ai modifié le nom de la boutique`

Answer (score 1):

In your insertBoutique function, you are specifying the key of your inserted row with the following:

```
values.put(BTK_KEY, boutiq.getBTQKey());
```

Try removing this line of code.

In general, if you have an automatic SQL field such as a primary key with auto-increment, you should not specify the field in your insert statement. In the Android SQLite wrapper, this means you should not insert the key into your ContentValues object; it will then be removed from your SQL insert. This may be causing your problem.

If that doesn't work, please post your logs / stack trace for a better chance at finding the issue.

Comment: I've done what you told me, and I've remove the - ' - of my task in the Main: test.setBTQName("J'ai modifié le nom de la boutique");                                              And now I've got this message in my logcat:                                            D/BDD_Operation: mise a jour quasi terminée
E/SQLiteLog: (1) near "ai": syntax error
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM

Comment: beginning of crash
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                       Process:  PID: 2486
ComponentInfo{.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "ai": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: UPDATE tableBoutique SET boutiqueClockPm2=?,boutiqueClockPm1=?,boutiqueClockAm2=?,boutiqueTelephone=?,boutiqueClockAm1=?,boutiqueNom=?,boutiqueLogo=?,boutiqueType=?,boutiqueSite=? WHERE boutiqueNom = J ai modifié le nom de la boutique

Comment: Most likely the problem is that you are using an apostrophe (character ') in your name. When this value gets inserted into a SQL query, SQL interprets that as an end quote and the rest of your string is interpreted as SQL, which fails. This is why you should always escape strings before inserting them into your database.Try the function DatabaseUtils.sqlEscapeString(string).